# Getting NullPointerException at SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I am getting NullPointerException at SharedPreferences. Here is my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
            final String number = phone.getText().toString();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setMessage("Confirm your number:+91-" + number)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                            editor.putString(Phone, number);
                            editor.commit();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Navigationfarmer.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        }
```

Logcat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at wolverine.example.com.btp_farmer.MainActivity$1$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
>        
> at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage (AlertController.java:166)
>        
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>        
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   (MainActivity.java:43):SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

Comment: Where is  sharedpreferences variable assigned on which you are calling the edit method....`sharedpreferences.edit()`. Post the code of that too

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ,http://justpaste.it/maam

Comment: put your `MainActivity` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(NAME,   
 Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "ABC");
 editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not assigned the sharedpreferences variable hence its null.
First assign the sharedpreferences then call the edit() method.

Use the below code:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
```